# how to create alias for #include<stdio.h> in vim

Tags: c, unix, vim, alias

everytime we write a program we need something like #include or any other #include things...

Is there anyway to create alias for this, so that when I type inc in vim and press some key, then inc changes to #include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in .vimrc:

```
iabbrev _istd #include <stdio.h><CR>
```

Now if you type `_istd` you will get the include pasted. You can have several includes like this:

```
iabbrev _istd #include <stdio.h><CR>#include <stdlib.h><CR>#include <string.h><CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

Read `:h abbreviations` or try one of [the many snippet expansion plugins available](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=snippet&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search).

I use the original [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim), but there is [a modern fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and a modern alternative called [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715).

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your .vimrc file

```
map ù :s/inc/#include \<stdio.h\>/<CR>
```

Select text, press ù and inc changes to #include